# Prove the thickness of the complete graph $K_7$ is 2

Tags: graph-theory

I know the theorem: If $G$ has $p$ vertices and $q$ edges, then the thickness of $G\ge\frac q{3p-6}$.

So in this case, the thickness of $K_7$ is at least 2, but how can we show that it is not 3 or 4…

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partition of the edges of $K_7$ into two planar graphs that proves that thickness of $K_7$ does not exceed 2:
[image: Partition of edges of K_7 into two sets: K_5 without two edges and the rest.]

Answer (score 1):

[image]
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$